# Incorrect Measure result

Tags: ssas

I have a fact table X with Column Y and I have add it that column as a measure on SSAS 2012. The properties of that measure are AggregateFunction: Sum, DataType: Integer, source: X.Y, DataType: Integer, BindingType: Column binding, NullProcessing: Automatic.

On measure Group Properties, Error Configuration ReportAndStop, Key ErrorAction: DiscardRecord, KeyErrorLimit:0, KeyErrorLimitAction: stopprocessing. IgnoreUnrelatedDimensions:True.

When I add (only) this measure on the browser Grid I get 318597 and when I exec `SELECT SUM(Y) FROM X` I get 990416. The same happens when I use the date dimension for year 2015 & 2016.                                                                                          The data are for testing. Any thoughts from where to start? Is wrong the sql query compared to SSAS measure?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is likely to be in the dimensions that relate to this measure-group.  Your SQL query is covering the entire fact table.  Your result in the browser is only covering that part of the fact table that corresponds to a dimension member in every dimension that slices it.  There must be rows in the fact table that don't relate to any member in at least one dimension.

This would most likely be because some dimension members have not loaded, or (before we even get to the SSAS stage), the fact table itself already contains rows that have a missing dimension key.

A better comparison would be

```
SELECT SUM(Y) FROM X
INNER JOIN Dimension1 ON [something]
INNER JOIN Dimension2 ON [something else]
...
```

If that gives the same result as the browser grid, there's nothing going wrong in the cube processing.  If not, the problem is in the processing: probably dimension members not making it from the source into the dimension.

Comment: Runninq the query with the inner joins from SSMS i get bigger number compared to SSAS (Join with the 4 Dims). I have Fact A with regular connections to Dim1, Dim2, Dim3 & Dim4. In the dimension structure of Dim4 I have included attributes of 4 related tables. I have created user hierarchies which all of them end to Dim4.Id

In order to check the result of measure I have to join only the Dim 1-4 or/and the 4 related tables of Dim4?

Comment: You have to join to what is going to end up being the population of Dim4.  Check the datasource of this dimension: from what you say it's probably Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 INNER JOIN Table3 INNER JOIN Table 4.  I'd start with checking that the population of this dimension (in SSAS) matches what you think it should be (in the SQL source).

Comment: Check out this article as well: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174774.aspx.  I suspect that you're getting dimension keys in your fact table that don't match any dimension key - but how SSAS will handle this depends on the options you set for processing.